# How does one provide a determinant as input to Wolfram Alpha?

Tags: wolfram-alpha

$\begin{vmatrix}
17&-12&4&0\\
5&9&-2&1\\
3&-6&-1&14\\
11&7&0&8\\
\end{vmatrix}$

How would one express the preceding determinant in the Wolfram Alpha™ environment?

Comment: I would try $\det(\{\{17, -12, 4, 0\},\{5, 9, -2, 1\},\{3, -6, -1, 14\},\{11, 7, 0, 8\}\})$.

Comment: I tip my hat to the fast fingers of Mr. @Git Gud: I had no sooner finalized the question than he had responded with an answer.

Comment: Thank you and please disregard my previous (now deleted) comment, I  had mistaken your answers with your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/Matrices.html for various different ways of doing it.